# Did Sultan Nur ad-Din stop two men from stealing the body of Muhammad in 1164 AD?

Tags: islam

The blog [Life in Saudi Arabia](http://lifeinsaudiarabia.net/blog/2015/03/17/first-attempt-to-steal-holy-body-of/) has a page on an event that supposedly happened in the year 1164 AD, summarized briefly as follows:

[Nur ad-Din](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nur_ad-Din_(died_1174)) had the same dream three times where he saw Muhammad, who showed him "faces". Taking these dreams as being prophetic, the Sultan went to Medina and gave alms to the people. He asked if there are other people that don't receive alms. There were two who didn't, and the Sultan located them and found out they were Christians who were digging a tunnel to try to steal Muhammad's body. The Sultan then had them killed.

[Google](https://www.google.co.id/search?q=thief+steal+muhammad+body&rlz=1C1JPGB_enID637ID637&oq=thief+steal+muhammad+body&aqs=chrome..69i57.5065j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) shows many slight variations on this story, so it is a notable claim.

Are there any records that this really happened?

Comment: Is that blog notable?

Comment: Miracle or fairy tale?

Comment: It'll be pretty difficult to prove or disprove whether [the guy a thousand years ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nur_ad-Din_(died_1174)) actually had this dream. A quick search of some of the things mentioned in the article(like the chamber being surround with 'melt lead') came up with nothing.

Comment: At best we could say that the sultan *said* that he had a dream prior to catching people trying to steal the body.

Comment: I have heard this story a few times I believe that it is NOTABLE. It's like Jesus' miracle.

Comment: If you're using the miracles of Jesus as your notability comparable, I think this might start running afoul of the "matters of faith" issue.

Comment: Are there any records that this is really happening? Is this a propaganda? Also the muslims don't believe in miracles. Nor do they think there is any supra natural revelation after Muhammad. I don't think this is faith.

Comment: Nobody can know for sure if he had dreams, prophetic or not. That's a matter of faith. Whether or not Nur ad-Din stopped two guys from stealing Mohammad's body is something concrete, so refocusing the question on that will make it on topic. I made some really major edits that I think will vastly improve this question and prevent it from being closed. Hopefully it still looks OK to you @SharenEayrs.

Comment: So basic stuff from that story, the Kingdom of Iberia was a kingdom located in the Caucasus mountains that ceased existing almost 1000 years before the story took place, there was no "Kingdom of Iberia" in terms of a Christian King of the Iberian peninsula or an actual title that ever existed.  https://www.quora.com/What-happened-to-the-prophet-Mohammads-body from quora, the top answer by a "Student of Islam" says there is no authentic proof.

Comment: [This source](http://www.radioislam.org.za/a/index.php/library/151-muhammad-sallallahu-alayhi-wa-sallam/10147-attempts-to-steal-the-body-of-the-prophet-sallallahu-alayhi-wa-sallam-and-his-companions.html) says [Samhoudi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali_ibn_Ahmad_al-Samhudi) wrote about this story. Maybe someone can use this to find the origin of the story.

Comment: I think the part of the dream one is beyond sceptic. But if someone says I have a dream, and latter see some guy in his dream and that some guy has a tunnel to some relic, now that's something very interseting